# Dpkg error when make apt-get install

Tags: pi-3, apt, dpkg

When I try to install a package, I get this error every time:

```
Setting up ntp (1:4.2.6.p5+dfsg-7+deb8u2) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Job for ntp.service failed. See 'systemctl status ntp.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript ntp, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package ntp (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
ntp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
```

When i run systemctl status ntp.service:

```
* ntp.service - LSB: Start NTP daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/ntp)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-03-10 15:25:53 WET; 2min 9s ago
  Process: 13832 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/ntp start (code=exited, status=2)

Mar 10 15:25:53 raspberrypi ntp[13832]: /etc/init.d/ntp: 6: /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/20-left-info-blocks: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
Mar 10 15:25:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: ntp.service: control process exited, code=exited status=2
Mar 10 15:25:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start NTP daemon.
Mar 10 15:25:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit ntp.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

I tried restart service, but fails...

What's wrong?

Comment: what does 'systemctl status ntp.service' and 'journalctl -xn' say?

Comment: i updated my question with yours..

Comment: Why are you trying to install `ntp`? It is installed and running on Rasbpian, and most distributions for the Pi.

Comment: DO you understand the question? This is a ntp error when i'm trying to install all packages..